# Grafana table /InfluxDB merge series by tag

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have data in influxdb that looks like this:

```
veeam_backup_status,brhost=vbr,job="PM20_DEVFA_SP16",vm=AAC-AXIOM 2022-01-09=1 1641708000000000000
veeam_backup_status,brhost=vbr,job="PM20_DEVFA_SP16",vm=AAC-AXIOM 2022-01-10=1 1641708000000000000
veeam_backup_status,brhost=vbr,job="PM20_DEVFA_SP16",vm=AAC-AXIOM 2022-01-11=1 1641708000000000000
veeam_backup_status,brhost=vbr,job="PROD ASSOC BackuP",vm=AAC-UTILITY 2022-01-09=1 1641708000000000000
veeam_backup_status,brhost=vbr,job="PROD ASSOC BackuP",vm=AAC-UTILITY 2022-01-10=1 1641708000000000000
veeam_backup_status,brhost=vbr,job="PROD ASSOC BackuP",vm=AAC-UTILITY 2022-01-11=1 1641708000000000000
```

I am trying to create a table in Grafana that groups series together by "vm" into a single row.

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bexkW.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60kue.png)

The query I am using is `SELECT * FROM "veeam_backup_status" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "vm" fill(null)`

I have been unable to find a transform that gets me what I want.  The data that is input into influx is generated by a powershell script so I can change the structure of it if it will make it easier.